# redirection from port 443 to 8443 not working from external for standalone tomcat

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat7, iptables

I have a ec2 instance with centos and a tomcat server running on it on port 8080.
My security group has an open port for HTTPS (443)

For the redirection I've added the following iptables rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

Now i can connect from my instance to port 443 and get redirected to port 8443.

https://localhost

https://54.247.86.18 (elastic ip)

But from external this doesn't work. If I connect to https://54.247.86.18 from browser I get an no server found error.

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: Just to check, is the EC2 instance in a public subnet? (Is there an internet gateway?)

Comment: @PMah there is application loadbalncer which is listening on instance:443

Comment: Ok... can you reach the instance at `https://load-balancer-dns-name`?

Comment: @PMah  I am not able access via https://load-balancer-dns-name too

Comment: What security group does your load balancer have?